Django tried these URL patterns, in this order http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ifconfig/
I have a problem with urls in my project, I can't understand why I getting error:
Request Method:GET
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ifconfig/
Using the URLconf defined in commands.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
The current path, api/ifconfig/, didn’t match any of these.
My files:
settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
   'api'
]


commands/urls.py:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
]


api/urls.py:

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('ifconfig/', views.IfconfigView.as_view(), name='ifconfig-api'),
    path('touchfile/', views.TouchFileView.as_view(), name='touchfile-api'),
]


I tried to change urlpatterns, tried to use AI, but nothing. Please help...

What is the name of the project, is commands.urls the ROOT_URLS (in the settings)?

Name of project - commands
Folder of project - Project2

so where does ROOT_URLS points to?

ROOT_URLCONF = 'commands.urls' Sorry, Im newbie

Can you show your api views.py?
